# UINavigationController of UIViewController is nil, after pushViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I'm using the `ECSlidingViewController` for my navigation menu, whenever I want to push a `UIViewController` from this menu, the `UINavigationController` of the pushed `UIViewController` is always nil.

The `UINavigationController` is initialized, the `NSLog` output shows the following `<UINavigationController: 0x8a80770>` address. When I call the method `pushViewController:animated` the `UIViewController` gets pushed but the `UINavigationController` is nil, therefore I can't see the `UINavigationBar` in this controller.

Here is the code snippet I'm using for this:

```
RecommendationsViewController *rvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RecommendationsViewController"];
[self.transitionsNavigationController pushViewController:rvc animated:NO];
self.slidingViewController.topViewController = rvc;
```

In `viewDidLoad` the `transitionNavigationController` get's initialized with (please note the `slidingViewController` is from the ECSlidingViewController project on github https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController and is of type `ECSlidingViewController`):

```
self.transitionsNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.slidingViewController.topViewController;
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: plz post ur portion of code

Comment: you didn't add the code for `self.transitionsNavigationController`

Comment: stop drip feeding lines of code. same thing again, where is `self.slidingViewController.topViewController` coming from. Post all of the code all the way up until we see an ` [[ alloc] init]`, your asking why its nil, and won't show us where your allocate it

Comment: It seems that the problem has to do with `Storyboard`, `self.slidingViewController.topViewController` has to be a `UINavigationController`, therefore I guess it is not possible to push a normal `UIViewController`, I solved the problem now, to set the property only to `UINavigationController` in the storyboard.

Comment: Don't forget to mark top answer and upvote any answer that solved your problem. Others facing the same issue will want to know what solved your problem and those putting in the time to answer your question deserve the rep points

Comment: Also don't forget to remove downvote if you could answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood how this is suppose to work.

The `UINavigationController` has to be the `topViewController`.

Don't reassign the `topViewController` after you do a push. By doing this:

```
self.slidingViewController.topViewController = rvc;
```

All that is going to do is set the current window to display that `UIViewController`, thats why you didn't see the nav bar, the app needs to display the `UINavigationController` which in turn will manage a list of `UIViewController`'s

The navigation controller handles a stack of viewControllers, just push the new `UIViewController` and nothing else

Comment: What is a `UINavigationViewController`? When I'm doing this `self.slidingViewController.topViewController = rvc` the `UIViewController` gets pushed but without a nav bar. I guess it is not possible to set a `UIViewController` as topViewController, it has to be a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: @user1463853 that was a typo on my part, clearly I meant a `UINavigationController`. Please read my answer again, all you did was post your last comment which my answer was in response too.

Comment: thanks to your lovely help I could figure a way out to solve this issue. I'm casting now the topViewController to a `UINavigationController` like this `UINavigationController *navC = (UINavigationController*)self.slidingViewController.topViewController;` then pushing the `UIViewController` works perfectly fine:

`[navC pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RecommendationsViewController"] animated:YES];`

Comment: @user1463853 yes that looks about right. Glad I helped. Don't forget to mark my answer as top answer and upvote so others will know it fixed it when facing the same issue and I get the rep points for fixing it

Comment: will do, I'm not sure if you downvoted my question or anyone else? If so, please remove the downvote, because you were able to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a related issue where a Navigation controller's topViewController will forget that it is attached to a navigationController.

My Storyboard setup is:  ->NavigationController->ViewController
The connection between NavController and ViewController is "root view controller".
I have set a storyboardID for each of these view controllers.

I have a view management class "ViewManager" that contains weak references to all storyboard views, which I obtain using:

```
_rootNC = [self.mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavController"];
//ViewController gets auto-attached to the NavController, and so viewController.navigationController == NavController

_firstVC = [self.mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
//Instantiating the ViewController again clears its navigationController property, and so viewController.navigationController == nil
```

I suppose one shouldn't gain a hook into Storyboard Instances by reinstantiating the views.  I'd appreciate if others would share their best-practices for obtaining weak references to storyboard viewControllers in such a way that I could control them in a single viewManager class.  (I'm leaning toward setting viewManager.rootNC from within NavigationController's viewDidLoad).